# export keyword issue with jest on Node 14 & Next.js framework while running test case

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to run a test case but it is giving me the below error:

/Users/rkaur/Documents/GitHub/Kmart/store-integrity-ui/node_modules/@kmartau/producer-api/dist/index.js:1
({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from './lib/producer-api';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

I have  installed a NPM package from my GitHub @kmartau/producer-api. And using it like
import { updateTask } from '@kmartau/producer-api';

But while running test case the above mentioned error is coming.

jest.config.ts

/*

- For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
- https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
  */

```
module.exports = {
  // Use ts-jest for compiling transpiling tests
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@lib/(.*)': ['<rootDir>/lib/$1'],
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    'd3': '<rootDir>/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',

  // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
  clearMocks: true,

  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest-setup.ts'],

  // Run coverage reports while executing tests
  collectCoverage: true,

  // Where to write coverage reports
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",

  // Regexp pattern for excluding paths from coverage reporting
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/cdk/', '/src/test-utils.tsx'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/cdk/'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns:  ['/node_modules/', '/cdk/'],
  watchPathIgnorePatterns:  ['/node_modules/', '/cdk/'],

  // The provider to use when instrumenting code for coverage
  coverageProvider: "babel",

  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 70,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 80,
    },
  },

  globals: {
    // We must specify a custom tsconfig for tests because we need the typescript transform
    // to transform jsx into js rather than leaving it jsx such as the next build requires.  you
    // can see this setting in tsconfig.jest.json -> "jsx": "react"
    // Credit: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8663
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "tsconfig.jest.json"
    }
  },
  projects: ["<rootDir>/jest.config.js"]
};
```

I added   'd3': '/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js', in moduleNameMapper to resolve it but nothing happens. I want the test case to run successfully

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).